# Doesn't compile addthis on iOS

Tags: ios, addthis

I followed the [quick guide to install AddThis](http://support.addthis.com/customer/portal/articles/381270-addthis-for-ios-quick-start-guide#.UZ5WamRgby8) and I don't know what is wrong, but I can't compile.

I have this errors:

```
Undefined symbols for architecture armv7:
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_AddThisSDK", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in FinishingScene.o
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_FBSession", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in AppDelegate.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture armv7
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Did you reference all the frameworks that AddThis requires? http://support.addthis.com/customer/portal/articles/381270-addthis-for-ios-quick-start-guide#.UZ5evytWo6I

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I haven't used AddThis, but this smells like the library isn't added in to the project properly.

Click on your target, then `Build Phases`, then expand `Link Binary With Libraries`. Make sure all the `.a` and `.framework` files you added to the project are listed there.